# Clean Up Tracking points selects all points no matter what

Tags: tracking

here's my steps:

1. Open footage in movie clip editor.
2. Adding tracking points and track forward/backwards
3. I get a solve error of let's say 2
4. Now when I'm trying to clean up tracks from the left panel, it will select all the tracks no matter what value I put in Frames or Error, and when selecting different track points I KNOW they have different solve errors.

It's not like I haven't done any tracking before. Never had this issue until now. Been looking back at many different video tutorials and followed every step, but still, this clean up won't work correctly.

Anyone else ever had this issue?
Thanks in advance.